# Exe running as a Service instead of a Application

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

**Situation**

I have a Win 2012 server in which i run an exe which is essentially a GUI. The server restarts every monday so on monday morning i have to log-on to the server using a generic account and manually start the exe.

**Setup**

I am planning to automate the activity of starting the exe every monday. For that i have written a batch file which starts the exe with some parameters. Also i have created a scheduled task that runs on Monday and triggers the batch file. The trigger that i have used in the scheduled task is "At Startup".

**ISSUE**

The issue that i am facing is that after the server is restarted i am not seeing my GUI(exe) running. When i checked on the Task Manager it is showing it running as Background Process however it is not coming to front and i am not seeing the GUI. I might be wrong but i think the exe is running as a process/service instead of running as an App.

Can someone please suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what in particular you want to achieve. Can you ***edit*** the question to clarify? E.g., run as a service hosted by SCM, run a GUI application as the logged in user, run a console application hidden, &c. &c.

Comment: @chwarr I have edited the question with full details. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: Much, much, much better question.

Comment: Excuse me, but does Win2012 lack such a simple thing as the "Startup" for applications? I mean, even if it's a simple application, there were always at least two ways to run them on system startup.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the two methods.

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work the way you want it to.  Generally speaking, servers show GUI for logged in users.  If you run the program when no one is logged into the machine, the GUI doesn't have a desktop to show on.  The best solution is to separate the back end process from the GUI and run the first when the machine is started and the second for each user during login.